# HttpException: A public action method 'ListCheckListType' was not found on controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, httpexception

I checked all the solutions but still doesnt work.I got a partial view page in layout page and When ı run only partial page it works but when ı run another page with layout it doesnt work.

I hope you can help me

Here is my Model :

```
    public CheckListType CheckListType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CheckListTypeList1 { get; set; }
```

And my Controller :

```
    public ActionResult ListCheckListType()
    {
        ControlListTypeModel listTypeModel = new ControlListTypeModel();
        List<SelectListItem> CheckListTypeList = new List<SelectListItem();
        foreach (CheckListType item in checklisttypeRepository.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            CheckListTypeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.CheckListTypeId.ToString(), Text = item.CheckListType1 });
        }
        listTypeModel.CheckListTypeList1 = CheckListTypeList;
        return PartialView("~/Areas/User/Views/CheckList/ListCheckListType.cshtml", listTypeModel);
    }
```

View :

```
    @using TodoListApp.Areas.User.Models.ViewModel
    @model ControlListTypeModel
 <form action="/CheckList/ListCheckListType" method="get">
 <div>
    CheckListType :
 </div>

 <div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelitem=>modelitem.CheckListType.CheckListTypeId,Model.CheckListTypeList1)
    <button type="button" class="butt button bg-info" style="height:40px; width:98px;">Choose CheckListType</button>
</div>
```

Layout :

```
  <div class="container body-content">
    @Html.Action("ListCheckListType");

    @RenderBody(){
    }

    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p> @DateTime.Now.Year </p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

HttpException: A public action method 'ListCheckListType' was not found on controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because it searches `ListCheckListType` action in wrong controller while rendered in partial view. Specifying controller name as well should fix the exception

```
@Html.Action("ListCheckListType", "Home"); //if action is in HomeController
```